# How to return single node with Multiple match for different labels in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j 3.2.x. What I am try to do is write a query that will update relation between two nodes (User and Gender) and return single User node with InterestedInGender property pulled from relation as array. There is a problem with the below query as right now it returns multiple records with  single value for interestedInGender. Relations are created properly but when returning data it is returning multiple records. I just want to return User node. Is there any way we can fix this query to just return single user node.

```
MATCH (u:User {_id:"1234"}) 
MATCH (ig:Gender) WHERE ig.value IN ["male", "female"]
WITH u, ig
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[igr:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->()
DELETE igr
with u, ig
MERGE (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->(ig)
RETURN u{
  ._id,
  interestedInGender: [(u)-[:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->(ig:Gender) | ig.value]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting multiple records (rows) is because your `ig` match to gender matches to two :Gender nodes...two rows where both rows have the same `u` node, but different `ig` nodes. That cardinality remains throughout the rest of your query, and so you get two rows back.

You need to shrink the cardinality of `u` back down to 1 after you MERGE the relationship, so add this after your MERGE but before your RETURN:

```
WITH distinct u
```

Comment: I ended up doing this `MATCH (u:User {_id:"1234"})
WITH u
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[igr:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->()
DELETE igr
with u
UNWIND ["male", "female"] AS igender
MATCH (g:Gender {value: igender})
MERGE (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->(g)
with u, collect(g) as genders
RETURN u{
  ._id,
  interestedInGender: [(u)-[:INTERESTED_IN_GENDER]->(iig:Gender) | iig.value]
}`

Comment: I tried WITH distinct u as well, it did return single result but the value for interestedInGender was single value.